# Subsequent castings of Genesis to expand the demiplane, is the growth sudden or timed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, planes

The [genesis](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/spells/genesis.htm) demiplane can be expanded by further castings:

> Once the basic demiplane reaches its maximum size, the spellcaster can continue to cast this spell to enlarge the demiplane, adding another 180 feet of radius to the demiplane each time.

Now, is this growth sudden (the extra radius is added at once) or timed (it grows 1ft per day, just like the original growth)?

Answer (score 5):

*Genesis* says in part:

> **At first,** the fledgling plane grows at a rate of 1 foot in radius per day to an initial maximum […] **Once the basic demiplane reaches its maximum size,** the spellcaster can continue to cast this spell to enlarge the demiplane, adding another 180 feet of radius to the demiplane each time.

For each casting of *Genesis* after the first, the demiplane grows the additional 180 feet of radius "immediately" - though, since the spell takes a week to cast, a DM might choose to narrate that as the caster producing 1/7th of the demiplane each day.

Comment: Worth noting that it's immediately *after* the spell is cast (i.e. the one week casting time), not immediately as soon as it's cast.